# How to send a single shift key with SendKeys?

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, shift

I'm trying to automate a routine task with vbscript. It requires me first pressing a single shift and then input a string. How can I do that with SendKeys? If it can't be done, is there no way to automate this task without installing some new tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special character for the shift key is the plus sign.  Here is an article that explains further:
http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/01/21/qtp-vbscript-sendkeys-faq/

Comment: No way. I swear I've tried with that. Nothing happened. So I thought it only works as combinations. But it works now. I don't understand. Thank you anyway.